# A balanced coin is tossed four times.

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification

A balanced coin is tossed four times. List the possible outcomes and compute the probability of each of the three events:
(a) exactly three heads
(b) at least one head
(c) the number of heads equals the number of tails
(d) the number of heads exceeds the number of tails

My solution:

A balanced coin is tossed four times, So the possible outcomes can be following:

possible outcomes are 2 and trials are 4

Sample space is determined by= $2^4=16$

HHHH HTHH THHH HTHT

HHHT HTTH TTHH THTH

HHTT HHTH TTTH THHT

HTTT TTTT TTHT THTT

a) Probability of exactly three heads$=4/16=1/4$
b) Probability of At least one head$=15/16$
c) Probability of that the no. of heads equals the no. of tails$=6/16$
d) Probability of that the no. of heads exceeds the no. of tails$=4/16=1/4$

Could you see it for me is it correct?

Comment: d is incorrect.  P(H>T) = P(H=3)+P(H=4) = 5/16.

Comment: @shaihorowitz It was't there when I put in mine.  Why so defensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first $3$ answers are correct, but the $4$th answer is wrong:

- Probability of exactly $3$ heads $=\frac{\binom43}{2^4}=\frac{4}{16}$
- Probability of at least $1$ head $=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{4}\frac{\binom4n}{2^4}=\frac{15}{16}$
- Probability that the no. of heads equals the no. of tails $=\frac{\binom42}{2^4}=\frac{6}{16}$
- Probability that the no. of heads exceeds the no. of tails $=\sum\limits_{n=3}^{4}\frac{\binom4n}{2^4}=\frac{5}{16}$

Answer (score 0):

Your correct for the most part. Slight error in part d. Consider the Probability of that the no. of heads exceeds the no. of tails = probability of 3 or more heads = probability of 3 heads plus probability of 4 heads